# Python3 Pandas Dataframe KeyError Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have an Dataframe crawls, like following:
[image]

When I run this code

```
crawl_stats = (
crawls['updated']
    .groupby(crawls.index.get_level_values('url'))
    .agg({
        'number of crawls': 'count', 
        'proportion of updates': 'mean', 
        'number of updates': 'sum'
    })
```

It shows the error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-180f1041465d> in <module>
      8 crawl_stats = (
      9     crawls['updated']
---> 10         .groupby(crawls.index.get_level_values('url'))
     11         # .groupby('url')
     12         .agg({

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in _get_level_values(self, level)
   3155         """
   3156 
-> 3157         self._validate_index_level(level)
   3158         return self
   3159 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in _validate_index_level(self, level)
   1942         elif level != self.name:
   1943             raise KeyError('Level %s must be same as name (%s)' %
-> 1944                            (level, self.name))
   1945 
   1946     def _get_level_number(self, level):

KeyError: 'Level url must be same as name (None)'
```

And I tried this modified code:

```
crawl_stats = (
crawls['updated']
    # .groupby(crawls.index.get_level_values('url'))
    .groupby('url')
    .agg({
        'number of crawls': 'count', 
        'proportion of updates': 'mean', 
        'number of updates': 'sum'
    })
```

It also shows error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-8c5f0f6f7c86> in <module>
      9     crawls['updated']
     10         # .groupby(crawls.index.get_level_values('url'))
---> 11         .groupby('url')
     12         .agg({
     13             'number of crawls': 'count',       
3293             # Add key to exclusions

    KeyError: 'url'
```

I have already tried to do as other guidance in stack overflow before, but it still doesn't work yet.
Could anybody help me fix it? Thanks!

Here is my code to create the Dataframe crawls.

```
def make_crawls_dataframe(crawl_json_records):
    """Creates a Pandas DataFrame from the given list of JSON records.

    The DataFrame corresponds to the following relation:

        crawls(primary key (url, hour), updated)

    Each hour in which a crawl happened for a page (regardless of
    whether it found a change) should be represented.  `updated` is
    a boolean value indicating whether the check for that hour found
    a change.

    The result is sorted by URL in ascending order and **further**
    sorted by hour in ascending order among the rows for each URL.

    Args:
      crawl_json_records (list): A list of JSON objects such as the
                                 crawl_json variable above.

    Returns:
      DataFrame: A table whose schema (and sort order) is described
                 above.
    """
    url = []
    hour = []
    updated = []


    # To get the 1000 url, number of checks and positive checks
    for i in range(len(crawl_json_records)):
        temp_url = [crawl_json_records[i]['url']]
        temp_len = crawl_json_records[i]["number of checks"]
        temp_checks = crawl_json_records[i]["positive checks"]

        # url.append(temp_url*temp_len)
        for item0 in temp_url*temp_len:
            url.append(item0)
        # hour.append(list(range(1,temp_len+1)))
        for item1 in list(range(1,temp_len+1)):
            hour.append(item1)
        temp_updated = [0]*temp_len

        for item in temp_checks:
            temp_updated[item-1] = 1
            # updated.append(temp_updated)
        for item2 in temp_updated:
            updated.append(item2)

    # print('len(url):',len(url))
    # 521674
    # print('len(hour):',len(hour))
    # print('len(updated):',len(updated))
    # Above 3 is 521674
    #print(type(temp_len))
    #print(temp_len)
    #print(temp_url*temp_len)

    columns = ['url','hour','updated']
    data = np.array((url,hour,updated)).T
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)
    df.index += 1
    # df.index = df['url']
    return df.sort_values(by=['url','hour'], ascending=True)

crawls = make_crawls_dataframe(crawl_json)
crawls.head(50)  # crawls shows as the image
```

Comment: It is always recommended to post samples in text not in image please, kindly edit your post and let us know then.

Comment: What is `print (crawls.columns.tolist())` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 problems - need grouping by column `url` and also define list of tuples for new columns names with aggregated functions:

```
crawls = pd.DataFrame({
    'url': ['a','a','a','a','b','b','b'],
    'updated': list(range(7))
})
print (crawls)
  url  updated
0   a        0
1   a        1
2   a        2
3   a        3
4   b        4
5   b        5
6   b        6

d = [('number of crawls', 'count'), 
     ('proportion of updates', 'mean'), 
     ('number of updates', 'sum')]
crawl_stats = crawls.groupby('url')['updated'].agg(d)
print (crawl_stats)
     number of crawls  proportion of updates  number of updates
url                                                            
a                   4                    1.5                  6
b                   3                    5.0                 15
```

EDIT:

Problem with son numeric column should be converting to numpy array, better is create dict and pass to DataFrame construcor:

Change:

```
columns = ['url','hour','updated']
data = np.array((url,hour,updated)).T
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)
```

to:

```
columns = ['url','hour','updated']
df = pd.DataFrame({'url':url, 'hour':hour,'updated':updated}, columns=columns)
```

Comment: I modified my code according to your guidance, but it sill shows error as what I edited my post.          DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

Comment: @pandalai - it seems your `update` column is not numeric, try `crawls['updated'] = crawls['updated'].astype(float)` before my solution.

Comment: Thank you for your help! @jezrael    And it finally works!

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace this:

```
.groupby(crawls.index.get_level_values('url'))
```

with:

```
.groupby('url')
```

Because you don't have index in you DataFrame.

Comment: I modified my code according to your guidance, but it sill shows error as what I edited my post. Could you give me help?

Comment: Check comment under question, what is `print (crawls.columns.tolist())` ? Because `Keyerror` means no column `url`